# How to change value dict out class

Tags: python

I want to change dict value, but allert me a Error 'object does not support item assignment'

Full Code:

````
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = dict()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.dict[item]


arr = SparseArray()
arr[0] = 1```
````

Comment: If you have defined `__setitem__` for the class

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to override `__setitem__`

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.dict[key] = value
```

Then you'll be able to assign a value using an index

```
# use of __setitem__
arr[0] = 1
arr["foo"] = 5

# use of __getitem__
print(arr[0])  # 1
print(arr["foo"])  # 5
```

---

Also avoid naming variable as built-in name like `dict`, at least you can use `items` or `values` if there is no real sense about the variable's content